# Docker run error -> EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '/app/node_modules' -> '/app/.build/node_modules'

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a node-typescript app using Docker. The image builds fine using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-nodejs6.10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN npm install --global yarn
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn global add serverless@~1.24.1

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "yarn", "run", "deploy" ]
```

But when I try to run it I get the following Error:

```
EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '/app/node_modules' -> '/app/.build/node_modules'
```

UPDATE:
Apparently the same problem [happens with Ember](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-htmlbars/issues/104), but I'm not using it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it by adding this

```
.build/
```

to the `.dockerignore` file, rebuild the docker image and the error is gone